# the lambda function how to visit the external array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
       for(i=0;i<5;i++){
       var ids=[1,2,3,4,5];
        $("#btn"+ids[i]).click(function(){
             alert("btn"+ids[i]);
        });
       }
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="btn1">按钮1</button>
<button id="btn2">按钮2</button>
<button id="btn3">按钮3</button>
<button id="btn4">按钮4</button>
<button id="btn5">按钮5</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Clicking the button should alert the value in the array, but it instead alerts `btnundefine`.

How can I visit the value in the external array in the lambda function?

Comment: Move the array declaration outside the loop

Comment: i had tried it,but it doesn't work

Comment: Actually, the outside array _is_ accessible. It's printing undefined because the index is outside the array's range once for loop completes. By the time it enters the event handler, `i` is 5. `ids[5]` is `undefined`.

Comment: in the for loop,i<5, so dont't have the ids[5],the max is the ids[4],it's not outside the array's range,not???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define i with `let`. Otherwise, it will try to access ids[5] and prints undefined because ids array only has 5 elements.

```js
$(function(){
   var ids=[1,2,3,4,5];
   for(let i=0;i<5;i++){
      $("#btn"+ids[i]).click(function(){
         alert("btn"+ids[i]);
    });
   }
});
```

```html
<script  typetype=="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn1">按钮1</button>
<button id="btn2">按钮2</button>
<button id="btn3">按钮3</button>
<button id="btn4">按钮4</button>
<button id="btn5">按钮5</button>
```

Comment: alert("btn"+ids[i]); have the cost of concatenation. this.id is the perfect.

Answer (score -1):

This is workable also:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    var ids=[1,2,3,4,5];
       for(i=0;i<5;i++){

       console.log("#btn"+ids[i]);
        $("#btn"+ids[i]).click(function(){
             alert(this.id);

        });
       }
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="btn1">按钮1</button>
<button id="btn2">按钮2</button>
<button id="btn3">按钮3</button>
<button id="btn4">按钮4</button>
<button id="btn5">按钮5</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it also work,thank you very much,but i want to know this represent what?and why hava the id parameter?because i don't define the id

Comment: 'this' is a special keyword, in this case which is  refering to the button  which is clicked. Therefore it means that this.id is the id of the button which is clicked.

Comment: all right,i know something,thank you ,and i will found sometime to learn js deeply.

Comment: The question was on how to access the outside array, not how to alert the literal "btn1", "btn2" etc. The ID just coincidentally happens to have the same value as the string being alerted. What if OP was alerting "value=" instead?

Comment: en,what i want is to access the outside array,the answer1 use the let can accomplish it. i am doing the javaweb project and occur the similiar requestion.this is a example

Comment: i got you question.